# Given an ordinal with a particular cofinality, can we find other cofinal subsets with order type and cofinality at least that large?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals, well-orders

Followup to: [If $\omega^\alpha$ has cofinality $\omega^\beta$, and $\beta\le\gamma\le\alpha$, does it also have a cofinal subset of order type $\omega^\gamma$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903613/if-omega-alpha-has-cofinality-omega-beta-and-beta-le-gamma-le-alpha)

Say we have an ordinal $\omega^\alpha$ and suppose it has cofinality $\omega^\beta$, i.e., $\omega^\beta$ is the smallest order type of a cofinal subset.  (Note that $\omega^\beta$ must be a regular ordinal and in particular an initial ordinal.)  Pick $\gamma$ such that $\beta\le\gamma\le\alpha$, and such that, in addition, $\mathrm{cf}(\omega^\gamma)\ge \omega^\beta$ as well.

The question is: Must $\omega^\alpha$ have a cofinal subset of order type exactly $\omega^\gamma$?  If false as stated, is it at least true if we restrict to $\mathrm{cf}(\omega^\gamma)=\omega^\beta$?  What if we restrict to $\beta=1$?

**Edit**: As Andres Caicedo points out in the comments, we have to restrict to $\mathrm{cf}(\omega^\gamma)=\omega^\beta$.  But I don't currently see how to prove it true under that condition.

Notes: I originally asked this without the restriction on the cofinality of $\omega^\gamma$; Asaf Karagila pointed out that the statement was obviously false for cofinality reasons since cofinality is far from monotonic.  So, I've added a cofinality restriction to avoid that issue. :)

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot have cofinal sets of different cofinality. Requiring $\omega^\gamma$ to be of the right cofinality, you can find cofinal sets of that order type by a recursive construction.

Comment: OK, I think I see why the former is true -- if you have a cofinal set $B$ of type $\omega^\beta$ and any other cofinal set $C$, you could map each element of $B$ to the next element of $C$ after it to show that $C$ also has cofinality at most $\omega^\beta$.  However I don't see how to do the latter at the moment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I see how to do this now.  It's already been explained in the comments why this is impossible unless in fact $\mathrm{cf}(\omega^\gamma)=\omega^\beta$, so that answers that question.

So say $\mathrm{cf}(\omega^\gamma)=\mathrm{cf}(\omega^\alpha)=\omega^\beta$, $\gamma\le\alpha$.  Let $B\subseteq\omega^\gamma$ be cofinal of type $\omega^\beta$, $B'\subseteq\omega^\alpha$ cofinal of type $\omega^\beta$, and let $\phi:B\to B'$ be the isomorphism.

Induct on the elements of $B$ to build $\psi:B\to B'$ and $f:\omega^\alpha\to\omega^\gamma$; assume $\psi(c)$ is defined for $c<b$ and $f(x)$ is defined for $x<\psi(c)$ for some $c<b$.  Let $x_0$ be the supremum of all $c<b$ within $\omega^\gamma$, so it's the smallest element which hasn't had $f$ defined yet, and let $x'_0$ be the supremum of all $f(x)$ defined so far.

Then for our current $b\in B$, pick some $\psi(b)\in B'$ such that $\psi(b)\ge x'_0+b$ and $\psi(b)>\psi(c)$ for all $c\in B$ with $c<b$.  Then in particular, $\psi(b)\ge x'_0+(-x_0+b)$, so it's possible to choose $f$ so as to map the interval $[x_0,b)$ into the interval $[x'_0,\psi(b))$.

When all this is done, we have an embedding $f:\omega^\gamma\to\omega^\alpha$; and since we must have $\psi(b)\ge \phi(b)$ for $b\in B$, it follows that the image of $f$ is cofinal.

Comment: Let $A$ be an ordinal and  $C\subset A.$ If $F:C\to A$ where $F(c)\geq c$ for all $c\in C$ then the order-type $ot (F(C))$ of the image of $C$ is $\leq ot(C)...$  Let  $A$ be a non-zero limit ordinal  and $B\subset A$ with $ot(B)=cf(A),$ and let $C\subset A$ with $\cup C=A.$  For $c\in C$ let $f(c)=\min \{b\in B: b\geq c\}$ and let  $g(c)=\min \{c^*\in C: c^*\geq f(c)\}$. Since $c\subset g(c),$   we have $A=\cup C\subset \cup g(C)\subset A,$ so $g(C)$ is co-final in $A.$ (continued  in next comment)

Comment: (continued). We have $f(C)\subset B$ so $ot (f(C))\leq ot (B). $ And $g(c)\geq f(c).$ Therefore  $ot (g(C))\leq ot (f(C)\leq ot (B)=cf(A).$..... But also $ot(g(C)\geq cf(A),$ so $ot(g(C)=cf(A)....$ Now $\cup g(C)=\cup C$   so $cf(C)\leq ot(g(C))=cf(A)....$  But  we also have $cf(C)\geq cf(A)$ (...because any $X\subset C$ with $\cup X=\cup C$ satisfies $ \cup X=A$ so $ot(X)\geq cf(A)$...) . Hence $cf(C)=cf (A). $

Comment: I hope those details are not too tedious. My point is that $g$ is an easily-defined function that  shows that $cf(C)=cf(A)$.